# SQL Trigger before insert issue

Tags: triggers, insert

I have a trigger with before insert option and inside the trigger I insert the data to the same table. How would SQL handle this kind of issues as this lead to creating infinite triggers.

For Example:

```sql
Create trigger trigger_name on Employee
before insert
as 
insert on table Employee values(1001, 'chas');
go
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here with this trigger?

Comment: What **database system** is this for?? Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific

Comment: The Database is SQL Server 2010. In the above scenario infinite triggers are called. So my question is how do the database handle these situations.